Generate variables through a loop in Python
I'm trying to solve multiple ordinary differential equations in Python using odeint. A simple version would look like:
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def lotka_volterra(xy, t):
    x, y = xy
    dxdt = x - x * y
    dydt = x * y -  y
    return [dxdt, dydt]

Solving:
x0 = 40 #Initial prey population
y0 = 9  #Initial predator population
initial_conditions = [x0, y0]
t = np.linspace(0, 300, 4000) 
solution = odeint(lotka_volterra, initial_conditions, t)

However, I have a more complicated system where I need to generate variables within the function and then write the DEs - the number of species and so on is not constant and is in the hundreds.
I have come up with the following code:
def setofequations(variables, t):
    species = []
    ucarrier = []
    R = []
    O = []
    for i in range(1, nspecies + 1):
        species.append('N_' + str(i))
        ucarrier.append('ucarrier_' + str(i))
        
    for i in range(1, nreactions+1):
        R.append('R_'+str(i))
        O.append('O_'+str(i))
    

Here, every element of every list species, ucarrier, R, I is a variable that has its own ODE that needs to be solved.
I want to be able to make each string in those lists a variable that can then be used in equations. Every solution I can find such as globals(), locals() doesn't seem to work for my specific requirement - they all have you outright assign some value to it.
I also require that the variable within a list be called using the corresponding index. For example, R[i] should give R_i.
Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Can you just use the index of the items in the list to get the ones you want?

An element of a list IS a variable. You can use it as you wish. Further, how are you even going to use your variables (which you intend to create in a loop) in your code?

Are you sure you don't just want a dictionary? (The most common solution to the anti-pattern of "variable variables" or "dyamic variables")

Psytho: My set of equations are such that I can write them out using just the indices, for example I write an equation for the i-th  R, O, the k-th ucarrier, species. Wouldn't the string 'N_1', which is what's stored in the lists, be different from the variable N_1 = 1, for example?
JNevill: If I were to write it as a dictionary, should the corresponding values just be variables with the same name as the strings (keys)? That would serve the purpose, but wouldn't those variables need to be previously defined?

from scipy.integrate import odeint
import numpy as np

def set_of_equations(variables, t, nspecies, nreactions):
    species = {}
    ucarrier = {}
    R = {}
    O = {}
    for i in range(1, nspecies + 1):
        name = 'N_' + str(i)
        species[name] = variables[name]

    for i in range(1, nreactions + 1):
        R['R' + str(i)] = variables['R' + str(i)]
        O['O' + str(i)] = variables['O' + str(i)]
    ucarrier['ucarrier'] = variables['ucarrier']

    # Now you can define your differential equations using these dictionaries
    # For example:
    dxdt = species['N_1'] - species['N_1'] * species['N_2']
    dydt = species['N_1'] * species['N_2'] - species['N_2']
    
    # Similarly, define other differential equations using R, O, ucarrier dictionaries

    return [dxdt, dydt]  # Return a list of differential equations

nspecies = 2
nreactions = 1
initial_conditions = {'N_1': 40, 'N_2': 9, 'R1': 0.1, 'O1': 0.2, 'ucarrier': 0.5}
t = np.linspace(0, 300, 4000)
solution = odeint(set_of_equations, list(initial_conditions.values()), t, args=(nspecies, nreactions))


I figured it out:
def setofequations(variables, t):
    species = variables[:nspecies]
    R = variables[nspecies:nspecies+nredox]
    O = variables[nspecies+nredox:nspecies+(2*nredox)]
    ucarrier = variables[nspecies+(2*nredox):]

easily achieves the desired results, variables need to be referenced by index instead of names.
